# NSPredicate count on a relationship attribute

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I have actually a core data entity called Show and for every show I have a relation ship called Schedule that contains an attribute called schedules which is an array.

What I want to do is to create a Predicate that checks for a given show's schedule if it has more than 1 item.

To do That I tried Two solutions :

1. `NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"schedule.schedules > 1];`
2. `NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"schedule.schedules.@count > 1];`

But None of them would work.

NB : schedules attribute is an stored in my Core Data as Transformable and declared as an id variable.

Answer (score 2):

A transformable attribute is stored as binary data, and it isn't unpacked until the container entity is loaded into memory. So, you can't use any kind of predicate based on a transformable attribute in a fetch. It will only work to filter the results of the fetch.

Cheap solution is to store a simple integer attribute with the count and use that.

Better solution is likely to add / change your entities so you use a relationship instead of a transformable.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, if I understand, there is no way to do that without changing Core Data Model ?

Comment: Yes, you will need to change the model in some way to solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"@count.schedule.schedules > 1];
```

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Malformed keypath: @count.schedule.schedules'

Comment: Sorry, I didn't test it. I am using '@avg.' in my code and I thought it was going to work with '@count.'

Comment: Just wondering if 'schedule.@count.schedules > 1', haven't tried neither